# Can IOS-XE handle multiple snmp-trap source?

Tags: snmp

we have multiple VRF on an ASR and the snmp traps should be sent on different VRFs.
All VRF has a dedicated Loopback interface which should be used as snmp trap source.

The **snmp-server trap-source INTERFACE** command can only be used for one interface. Is there any other way to do this? Maybe SNMPv3 supports it?

Comment: Are you trying to send certain traps to one destination, and other traps to another, Or, do you want all traps to go to multiple destinations?

Comment: I would like to send all traps to different destinations (with different source and VRF).

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you can find an IP address that's unique to all VRFs, you can place the source in its own VRF, then leak (or import) routes from the destinations in other VRFs.